# Use message retry for courier

Tags: masstransit, routing-slip, masstransit-courier

As you know, in Masstransit, we can set up a UseMessageRetry. This method can help us to retry the message sending process once more.
This process continues as long as we hit errors.
The problem that I have encountered is that this setting is a singleton for every message.
What I seek to have is to set a different configuration for a particular message(courier).

the setting I have set for all messages is as follows:

```
   config.UseMessageRetry(x =>
                {
                    x.Incremental(100,
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                });
```

I would be thankful if somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring message retry at the bus configuration level, that retry policy applies to all receive endpoints. To configure a different policy for specific receive endpoints, you'd need to specify a different retry policy in the receive endpoint configuration.

A better way to configure the receive endpoints if you're using `ConfigureEndpoints()` is to register an [`IConfigureReceiveEndpoint`](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.6.html#iconfigurereceiveendpoint) type and check the queue name to see if it matches an execute or compensate queue name, and apply a different retry in that scenario.